# VueJS: Pass Data Between Routers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have tried countless to pass data between views using props and can't seem to get it to work. The idea is to pass data from one route to the other and at the end display all user inputted data.

Component A

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'DependencyStatus',
  data: function () {
    return {
      efcForm: {
        born: false
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    processForm: function () {
      this.$router.push({name: 'student', props: {messaged: 1}})
      console.log({born: this.efcForm.born,})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Component B

```js
<script>

export default {
  name: 'StudentData',
  props: ['messaged'],
  data: function () {
      return {
          born: this.$route.messaged
      }
  },
  methods: {
      checkForm: function() {
          console.log({checkForm: this.born })
      }
  }
  
}
</script>
```

My routes:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/student',
    name: 'student',
    component: Student,
    props: true
  },
```

Comment: You can use `Vuex` for state management across components https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [***dynamic param***](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) to pass *data* from one route
>   component to another.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/student/:messaged', // <-- [1] Add dynamic param
    name: 'student',
    component: Student,
    props: true
  }
]
```

Component A:

```
methods: {
 processForm: function () {
  this.$router.push({name: 'student', params: { messaged: 1 } }) // <-- [2] pass `messaged` as param instead of prop
 }
}
```

Component B:

```
methods: {
 checkForm: function() {
  console.log({ messaged: this.$route.params.messaged }) // <-- [3] excess in the other component via route param
 }
}
```

*PS: In case of passing complex ds, consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)*